# Lists of lists of custom objects in Python

Tags: python, list

I am stuck trying to figure out how to declare lists of lists (of lists) of objects properly.  Consider the following Python code:

```
short_list = [] * 5
for in range(5):
  c = MyClass()
  short_list.append(c)

super_list = [[short_list] * 100] * number_of_users
```

super_list[0] is intended to be some list of other lists which contains information related to user 0, super_list[1] for user 1, continuing.  These lists ultimately organize groups of objects of type "MyClass".  My problem is that setting the values of list elements within super_list[0] also change the corresponding list elements in super_list[1].  super_list[0] and super_list[1] are always exactly the same.

How do I declare short_list and/or super_list to give me the same conceptual organization of lists that I am trying to achieve such that super_list[0] and super_list[1] act and behave as two separate lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must construct them manually:

```
super_list = []
for i in xrange(100):
    short_list = []
    for j in xrange(5):
        short_list.append(MyClass())
    super_list.append(short_list)
```

Or, shorter, although maybe less readable:

```
super_list = [[MyClass() for j in xrange(5)] for i in xrange(100)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`[] * 5` is equal to `[]` in Python (try it in the interactive interpreter or in IPython).

You want to *copy* the list when constructing the super_list. By default assigning a list (that's what goes on behind the `*` operator) only makes a new reference. Try this instead:

```
[ short_list[:] for stub in xrange(100) ]
```

That clones the list many times using slice syntax. That's the Pythonic way of shallow-copying a list.

If you need deep copy you can `import copy` and use the `deepcopy` method.

Comment: Still, `super_list[0][0] is super_list[1][0]`, although now you've solved the problem of `super_list[0] is super_list[1]`.

Comment: True, thank you. Added a coment re: deepcopy, although I gathered from the OP's question that deep copy wasn't needed.